# Excel VBA Automatic print range not working after update

Tags: excel, vba, label

I've been using this Excel VBA script combined with my label printing sheet, but suddenly it has stopped working. I think it has to do with a new update.
It's used to loop through my data and print multiple labels, but now it only prints one and stops, not going to the next line.

Can someone please take a look at the code and see if there is something that might be interrupting the process?

I'm getting type mismatch "13" error on this row:

`StartRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T4").Value`

This is the rest of the code:

```
Sub PrintOneShelf()
Dim NrPositions As Integer
Dim StartRow As Integer


Application.Calculate


    NrPositions = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T3").Value
    StartRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T4").Value
    PrintRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T5").Value

    Worksheets("Backside").PrintOut From:=1, To:=NrPositions, Copies:=1

    NrPositions = Worksheets("Frontside").Range("T3").Value
    StartRow = Worksheets("Frontside").Range("T4").Value

    Worksheets("Frontside").PrintOut From:=1, To:=NrPositions, Copies:=1
    Worksheets("Print Overview").Cells(PrintRow, 2).Value = "x"


End Sub
Sub PrintBackShelf()

Dim NrPositions As Integer
Dim StartRow As Integer


Application.Calculate


    NrPositions = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T3").Value
    StartRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T4").Value
    PrintRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T5").Value

    Worksheets("Backside").PrintOut From:=1, To:=NrPositions, Copies:=1
    Worksheets("Print Overview").Cells(PrintRow, 2).Value = "x"

End Sub

Sub PrintFrontShelf()

Dim NrPositions As Integer
Dim StartRow As Integer


Application.Calculate

    NrPositions = Worksheets("Frontside").Range("T3").Value
    StartRow = Worksheets("Frontside").Range("T4").Value
    PrintRow = Worksheets("Frontside").Range("T5").Value

    Worksheets("Frontside").PrintOut From:=1, To:=NrPositions, Copies:=1
    Worksheets("Print Overview").Cells(PrintRow, 3).Value = "x"



End Sub

Sub PrintBackShelves()

Dim StartRow

Application.Calculate

    PrintRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T5").Value

    Do While IsNumeric(PrintRow)

        Call PrintBackShelf
        Application.Calculate
        PrintRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T5").Value
    Loop

End Sub
Sub PrintFrontShelves()

Dim StartRow

Application.Calculate

    PrintRow = Worksheets("Frontside").Range("T5").Value

    Do While IsNumeric(PrintRow)

        Call PrintFrontShelf
        Application.Calculate
        PrintRow = Worksheets("Frontside").Range("T5").Value
    Loop

End Sub

Sub PrintShelves()

Dim StartRow

Application.Calculate

    PrintRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T5").Value

    Worksheets("Print Overview").Range("B5").End(xlDown).Value = ""

    Do While IsNumeric(PrintRow)

        Call PrintBackShelf
        Application.Calculate
        PrintRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T5").Value
    Loop



Application.Calculate

    Worksheets("Print Overview").Range("B5").End(xlDown).Value = ""

    PrintRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T5").Value

    Do While IsNumeric(PrintRow)

        Call PrintFrontShelf
        Application.Calculate
        PrintRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T5").Value
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check that Worksheet backside exists? Because if it exists, `StartRow = Worksheets("Backside").Range("T4").Value` works if the sheet exists.

Comment: Maybe the value in T4 can't be placed into an integer?  What is in T4 when it fails?

Comment: `Worksheets("Backside").Range("T4").Value` is most likely a formula and it has some type of error.